# What type of plug is this (larger than a europe round prongs)

Tags: plug, socket

I have this plug for a eletric shaver but it doesn't seem to be a europe plug. I need to buy a adapter from this to US but don't know what this is.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Israel comes to mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets

Answer (score 1):

I looked up *"Babyliss Men"* on Google and it looks like it's a French based company that sells cosmetic products (predominately shaving products but there's other products as well).

By the looks of it, this type of plugs looks larger. Since it's a French company, I would assume that it's a **Type E** plug, which the hot and neutral prongs look slightly larger than the *Type B* which is another European plug. Type E looks exactly the same as a Type F but if this was a French product, Type E would be the case. Therefore, you can get either Type F or Type E adapters.

Also, I can't see exactly what the power rating on that adapter but it looks like it says its voltage compatibility is from 100v to 240v. France uses 230v for their mains.

[Look on Wikipedia about mains and plug type.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country)

Answer (score 1):

Those plugs are the standard used in Switzerland and there is another version with a third offset centre prong which is for ground or earth.

Most of the adapters I see on sale in EU accept them.